# DFS target selection/ordering

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs, dfs-r

I have a DFS folder with two targets. The first to the primary file server and the second to a slow emergency backup file server to be used only in the event of a failure of the primary.

There is 'one-way' replication configured between the two.

Both targets are located at the same site. Is there anyway to ensure that target selection picks the primary one first every time? I currently just have the secondary target disabled.

Edit: I have tried to [Set Target Priority to Override Referral Ordering](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770290.aspx), but that doesn't seem to have worked either.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this [DFS Server Prioritization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb524795(v=vs.85).aspx) document? It sounds like even if both of your servers are in the same "site", you can still set a different "target priority" (according to that document). It sounds like this should prioritize the servers as you would expect from a client point of view.

Comment: I don't see a way to apply this to my DFS configuration.